# Using htmlentities in PHP with a WYSIWYG editor

Tags: php, wysiwyg, html-entities

I'm trying to add a simply WYSIWYG editor to a text-area tag on a page, but I also want to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. Unfortunately the two don't appear to work well togeather. I understand that there isn't going to be a 'right' answer to this, but want some help thinking through the issues that need to be considered here.

Here are extracts from the code to explain the issue a bit:

```
<html>
  <head>
  //I'm using NicEdit as my WYSIWYG editor
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="<?php echo($TargetURL); ?>" method="POST">
    <textarea id="fNotes" name="fNotes" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; ">
      <?php
        echo(htmlentities($show->Notes));
      ?>
    </textarea>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

$shows->Notes returns the value entered into fNotes when it is saved.

The text that was saved was something like:

```
"Random <b>words</b> stuck in to test the text<br>"
```

Many thanks

Comment: My initial thought was to create a function to strip out andy <script> tags that appear in the $shows->Notes field, but I'm not sure how much needs to be stripped away.